# MySQL LEFT JOIN order of ON conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a MySQL query with inner joins and one left join and a lot of data in my database, and it's running quite slow. This is roughly my query:

```
SELECT
    main_table.*
FROM
    main_table
INNER JOIN
    ...
LEFT JOIN
    second_table ON (main_table.id = second_table.ref_id AND second_table.type = 'foo' AND second_table.bar IS NULL
WHERE
    second_table.id IS NULL
;
```

An entry from `main_table` *may* have one or more referenced entries in `second_table`. I want to get all results from `main_table`, that either have no results in `second_table`, or only has irrelevant data in the second table (`type 'foo'` or `bar` is NULL).

Taking a look into the *EXPLAIN*, MySQL searches for `bar IS NULL` first, followed by `type = 'foo'`, that would still result in many thousands of result, whereas checking for `ref_id` first would only leave very few results to check the other conditions on.

I only have an index on `ref_id`, not for `type` or `bar` and I don't feel the need to index them if I could just get the query search for `ref_id` first.

*--EDIT: I noticed that on the copy of the database (where it has the actual data and runs slow) does also have an index on `type` and `bar` individually, so that's probably why MySQL prefers `bar` over the other keys. I'm considering a key spanning multiple fields.--*

Does anybody have an idea how to optimize this kind of query? Is it possible to force MySQL using a certain order in the *ON* conditions?

---

"Solution": I added an index spanned over all the relevant fields.

I don't consider this being a real solution, because I believe, it would also have been faster if the JOIN was done on the indexed `ref_id` first. It probably did so when that was the only index, however my colleague had the idea to add an index separately on the other fields as well for some reason, probably needed somewhere else in our application.

Comment: Even if you could guarantee an order, which I don't think you can, what might happen down the line if you change the query?  Then the order could change again.  Why not just add an index anywhere it might be useful?

Comment: I don't answer questions with the word 'wanna' in them. It's just a rule.

Comment: I am now googling "what is difference between wanna and want" ))

Comment: Add an index on all three columns in second_table, and check the results. The index should have the columns on ref_id, type and bar _in that order_.

Comment: There's a way to hint MySQL to use certain indexes, although I suspect your issue should be solved some other way, Using hints is not very common. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Comment: This could be useful to someone: [10 Ways to Improve sql query performance](http://www.developer.com/db/slideshows/10-ways-to-improve-sql-query-performance.html)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you move the "Irrelevant" rows to the where part?
Seems to me the DB should have an easier time joining the tables, and will use the index

Something like

```
SELECT
    main_table.*
FROM
    main_table
INNER JOIN
    ...
LEFT JOIN
    second_table ON main_table.id = second_table.ref_id 
WHERE
    second_table.id IS NULL OR 
    (second_table.type = 'foo' AND second_table.bar IS NULL)
```

Comment: That's what I thought first, too. Your query *includes* `type = 'foo'`, but I need to exclude them in the final result (note my `WHERE second_table.id IS NULL`). I want to exclude the main results if there's just one match in the second table that matches the conditions.

Comment: You mean that if a row in main_table has 1 relevant and 1 non-relevant row, it shouldn't appear in the result, but my query will have it. right?

Comment: Yeah, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL `JOIN` is faster then `LEFT JOIN` so you can write your query like this.

```
SELECT
    main_table.*
FROM
    main_table
INNER JOIN
    ...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT main_table.*,second_table.*  FROM main_table 

JOIN second_table ON main_table.id = second_table.ref_id AND

second_table.type = 'foo' AND second_table.bar IS NULL) AS main_table2 ON 

main_table2.id = main_table.id

WHERE
second_table.id IS NULL;
```